# Lists rearrangement after finishing a query

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, sqliteopenhelper

Creating a searchable contacts kind of app. Below is my code

```
public class EmployeeList extends Activity {

    protected EditText searchText;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor, listcursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    protected ListView employeeList;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);
        employeeList = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);

        listcursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM employee",null);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.employee_list_item, 
                listcursor, 
                new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
        employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

        public void search(View view) {
            // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
                    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
                                                    new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
                    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                                    this, 
                                    R.layout.employee_list_item, 
                                    cursor, 
                                    new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
                                    new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
                    employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);

                                        }
```

}

The issue is after clearing the word from the edittext. it should go back to previous listview i.e, it should show all values in the db.

[image]

Comment: @Jason I cant understand wat u r tryin to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a second cursor, you should use a [FilterQueryProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FilterQueryProvider.html) with your EditText to update perform multiple updates to the ListView much like an AutoCompleteTextView.

Or you could add a TextWatcher and change the cursor back to your first one whenever the length is becomes zero.